# Internship along with Google Summer of Code?

Tags: open-source, google, internship

I am wondering about how much time Google Summer of Code typically takes.  I do have an internship lined up for this summer, but GSoC seems like quite an awesome experience.  I also really want to get into Open Source development.  It states in the [FAQ](http://www.google-melange.com/document/show/gsoc_program/google/gsoc2013/help_page#11._How_much_time_is_required_to) that it's not a good idea to attempt both, but it doesn't give any specifics.  I'm wondering if it's feasible to do both.  Or would I be better off by trying to work on open source in my spare time?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having done both an internship and GSOC, I'd agree with the FAQ that it is not a good idea to attempt to do both at the same time.